# How to mark task as complete using JavaScript, AJAX in a Django App

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a todo(goal) list within my Django App. I am able to add steps to my todo list, however I cannot figure out how to mark the step as complete (set the 'done' boolean field true).

The step model I have includes a boolean field which I am trying to set to true when submitting the checkmark form. I've tried to use a variation of my new step form mark the step as complete but I've been unsuccessful so far.

```html
<form class='check_Mark' method='post' data-goal={{goal.pk}} data-step={{step.pk}} action="{% url 'check_mark' goal.pk %}">{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit"> Mark Complete </button> 
</form>
```

```
function qAll (selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector)
}
const checkMark = qAll('.check_Mark')
checkMark.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(item.dataset.step)
    console.log(item.dataset.goal)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: item.action,
        data: {
            'goal': item.dataset.goal,
            'step': item.dataset.step,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success')
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
})
```

```
    path('goal/', core_views.goal_list_view, name='user-profile'),
    path('goal/add', core_views.add_new_goal, name='add_goal'),
    path('goal/add_step/<int:pk>', core_views.add_new_step, name='add_step'),
    path('step/<int:pk>/', core_views.check_mark, name='check_mark'),
```

```
@login_required
def check_mark(request, pk):
    from core.forms import CheckListForm
    from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CheckListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            done = form.save(commit=False)
            done.person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
            done.goal = get_object_or_404(Goal, pk=pk)
            done.step = get_object_or_404(Step, pk=pk)
            done.done = True
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CheckListForm()
    return HttpResponse()
```

```
class Step(models.Model):
    """Model representing the steps for each goal"""
    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'steps')
    step = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_done = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class CheckListForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = ('done',)
```

The error I'm getting at the moment when submitting the form is

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/step/15/
Raised by:  core.views.check_mark
No Step matches the given query.

I'm relatively new to programming so I'm not sure if this is the only thing wrong or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use done.save() instead of form.save() and remove done.done = true because no use

Comment: This means you are step model is empty with given pk